# Issue in debugging android apps on a real device

Tags: android, eclipse

I am newbie for android development. I need to debug my apps on a real phone. I already have a **Samsung Galaxy y pro duos (GT-B5512)**. But it does **not detected** by AVD Manager when it is connected via USB even though I have enabled '**USB debugging**' option in the phone.

I tried to find a USB driver for my device, but could not find one.

I am using eclipse IDE on Windows 7 64bit OS.

Can somebody please help me on this regard...?

Comment: you must have to install drivers of ur device first.

Comment: "I tried to find a USB driver for my device, but could not find one." I think that is your problem...you should look for your phone's USB driver.

Comment: you must have got drivers CD along with the device??

Comment: I didn't get a drivers CD along with the device..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to download Samsung Kies for Samsung phones. http://www.samsung.com/in/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP

Comment: You are most welcome :) Plz upvote the ans if you think it is useful and then choose the most helpful one :)

Answer (score 3):

Samsung Galaxy Y Duos GT S-6102 USB Connection works only with USB 2.0. It won't work with USB 3.0. So install Samsung Kies on your system and make sure USB Port is USB 2.0 and not USB 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the Using Hardware Devices section in android SDK

http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

It tells you steps to connect a device to PC via USB port